# sharepoint list field value to check empty or null

Tags: javascript, custom-list

I have a list "Country" and field "state". I need javascript which need to check if field "state" is empty or null.
Below is my code. 
After `ProjGenFolderUrl = data.d.results[0].ProjGenFolder`;  I want to check if `ProjGenFolderUrl != null` then only proceed. please help with syntax

```
function GetAppsPath()
{

    try 
    {
        var listTitle2 = "Project Specific Applications"; //Specify List Name 
        getProjGen(PHPMaster,listTitle2,projectCode).done(function(data) {
            ProjGenFolderUrl = data.d.results[0].ProjGenFolder;

            alert(ProjGenFolderUrl);
            getAppsPath(PHPMaster,listTitle2,projectCode).done(function(data) {  
                //AppsPath = data.d.results[0].Application_x0020_Link;
                DFSPathUrl = data.d.results[0].DFSPath;
                alert(DFSPathUrl);
                CreateMAPDriveURL();
                //alert(MapDriveURL);                   
            });
        });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err.message);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your SharePoint version? I may be able to help if it is 2013 On-Premise.

Comment: it is sharepoint online, I need javascript

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure if my solution would help you. You might want to give it a try though just in case by opening the console and trying it. My solution is something like `document.querySelector("[title='The field title']").value`, where **The Field Title** will have to be retrieved by naviguating in the elements inspector, because the names are sometimes cut if they are too long. Also, you could try this one: `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='endOfYourFieldName']")[0].value`

Comment: I have edited my question. can you help with that

Comment: Looks like you're calling a function, `getProjGen()`. What it is expected to return?